# can we have project type as console application for Windows services?

Tags: c#, .net

can we have project type as console application for Windows services in .Net? Normally for windows service we have project type as Windows Application? And what is the need to do like this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by making the project type as Console

Comment: That is what I am not clear on! Are there any special scenarios where we go for this special approach?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
Here difference between Console application and Windows Application is in [Environment.UserInteractive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive(v=vs.110).aspx) property. But, it does not matter if you run Console Application as Windows Service :) So, no needs to select project type as Console Application.

But, if you need a Console for debugging you can add some code to show console for Windows Application:

```
internal static class ConsoleAllocator
{
    [DllImport(@"kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport(@"kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    const int SwHide = 0;
    const int SwShow = 5;


    public static void ShowConsoleWindow()
    {
        var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

        if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            AllocConsole();
        }
        else
        {
            ShowWindow(handle, SwShow);
        }
    }

    public static void HideConsoleWindow()
    {
        var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

        ShowWindow(handle, SwHide);
    }
}
```

So, you'll have a console and no need to switch project type to Console Application.

Comment: Console for debugging means printing error and messages from service at run time

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't have anything to do with console. In my project For windows service, they have chosen console application and running it as windows service. My questions is why can't we go for Windows Application as it is? Whats the need to chose Console Application and then again host it as Windows Service? Are there any special cases where we opt this behavior?